# разная длинна у одной строки

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var tyu="";
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'franshyza'
});

connection.connect();
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `ee`', function (error, results, fields) {
  // a1 из mysql в кодировке utf8!!!
  // a1='\xff\xff\xff\xff\x66\x0a\x4d\xdc\xb4\xb4\x69\x87\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
  // Но длинна a1=72
  // А a2=18 (как надо)
  // ПОЧЕМУ И КАК ИСПРАВИТЬ??((
 a1=results[0].ip;
});

connection.end();
var socket = require( "dgram" ).createSocket( "udp4" );
socket.on(
    "message",
    function ( message, requestInfo ) {
        );          
    //ПРОБЛЕМАаааааааааааааааааааа
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {    
        var a2='\xff\xff\xff\xff\x66\x0a\x4d\xdc\xb4\xb4\x69\x87\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00';
      console.log(a1.length ); 
      console.log(a2.length ) ;    
      var response = new Buffer(a2, 'ascii');
```

Comment: забавно, не распознались юникодные кода, если в а2 проэкранируете слэши длина у обеих станет 72

Comment: @Grundy, я вообще ничего не понял...

Comment: @Qwertiy, `\xff` код символа, из базы приходит обычна строка с 4 символами вместо одного: '\', 'x', 'f', 'f' - вот и разница :)

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, как сохраняются эти данные

Comment: как мне сделать чтобы а1 была так же равна 18?в mysql данные в utf8(если это имеет значение)

Comment: Grundy, это я понимаю, как получить то что мне нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам приходят вместо символов их шестнадцатиричные коды. Вам надо их преобразовать в нормальные символы с помощью `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(char,16))`

```
function charConvert(str){
    var a1 = [];
    a2.split("\\x").slice(1,a2.length).forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
        a1[i] = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(item,16));
    })
    return a1.join("");
}
```

Ну или как нормальный вариант, долго и нудно разбираться с кодировками. Попробовать там конвертировать в другую кодировку и отдать строку в изначально нормальном виде или послать какой-нибудь SQL на смену кодировки в нужную или изменить кодировку файла. В общем там смотреть надо.

Comment: Во спасибо огромное! Всё работает!